# Low resolution grub arch nvidia

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub, graphics, grub2-mkconfig

This is not a big deal but this has been frustrating for a while now.
My graphic card is an RTX 3070
When I boot with grub I am stuck with a very low resolution, probably 1024.
I checked the command `videoinfo` in grub prompt and it returns two possible resolutions, 860x480 or 1024x768
But when I boot from a ubuntu live CD though, the resolution is fine (let's say high enough).
I compared parameters passed to the kernel and tried to imitate in arch the one in ubuntu but without any success.

I have tried different combination but ATM my parameters are such as:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Arch"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nvidia-drm.modeset=1 quiet splash"
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos"
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=console
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=gfxterm
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-blue/black"
GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-cyan/blue"
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/boot/grub/arch.png"
GRUB_THEME="/usr/share/grub/themes/Vimix/theme.txt"
```

**EDIT:** I tried to set `GRUB_GFXMODE`with higher resolutions, `auto` and to specify the depth (`width x height x depth`) it had no effect

**EDIT2:** I used `videoinfo`not `vbeinfo`

Comment: Is the Ubuntu Live CD perhaps booting in UEFI mode, as opposed to your Arch being in BIOS mode (as evidenced by the availability of the `vbeinfo` command)? When you boot with Ubuntu Live, does the `/sys/firmware/efi/` directory exist? In UEFI mode, the GRUB video resolution information should be available with `videoinfo` instead of `vbeinfo`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I was acutally was wrong, I used videoinfo and not vbeinfo. Plus I assume that I boot in UEFI since the directory you mention exists.

Comment: Have you installed the nvidia package using pacman?

Comment: In both modes, the GPU firmware is ultimately responsible for providing the list of available video modes. In BIOS boot mode, the firmware is known as the VESA video BIOS extension, and in UEFI mode, it's usually [GOP](https://wiki.osdev.org/GOP). If you did not use the same boot mode with Ubuntu as with Arch, any differences in the firmware implementations might have explained the limited choice of resolutions. But if you are using UEFI boot with both OSs, that was not the reason and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I think it will remain a mystery as it is not worth spending so much time. Thanks for sharing the knowledge anyway!
NOTE: it did that with the two different Nvidia GPU I had over time

Comment: The thing about Arch is that it’s not always easy to get a thing to work. In my experience it’s because there was some package that needed to be added. I’ve a 100% success rate when I revisit the Arch wiki and go through it very carefully and ensure nothing was missed

Comment: Sometimes it’s a package, sometimes it’s config.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution) you set the resolution with the `GRUB_GFXMODE=` value in the `/etc/default/grub` file. It’s of the form width x height x colour depth. Multiple alternative resolutions can be specified.

Your configuration above would seem to specify just 1024 x 768

Don’t forget to update grub `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` after editing your file

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it made sense but I tried and it does not help :|